# Laravel where clause with DATEDIFF()

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, datediff

I need to get all records having DATEDDIFF() >30 and <60.

I have tried with a query but it is not working.

How i can get the data which is matching the condition.

My query is,

```
 $cur_date=Carbon::now();


 $data=DB::table('mailbox_log as ml')
->leftjoin('registration as r','ml.reg_id','=','r.id')
->leftjoin('company as cmp','r.sociale_id','=','cmp.id')
->select('ml.*','r.id','r.g_id','r.num','cmp.name')
->where(DB::raw('DATEDIFF(ml.sent_pst_date, "%Y-%m-%d")'),$cur_date->format('Y-m-d'),'>','30')
->where(DB::raw('DATEDIFF(ml.sent_pst_date, "%Y-%m-%d")'),$cur_date->format('Y-m-d'),'<','60')
->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with Carbon `addDays()`

```
 $start_date = (Carbon::now())->addDays(30);
 $end_date = $start_date->addDays(30);

 $data=DB::table('mailbox_log as ml')
->leftjoin('registration as r','ml.reg_id','=','r.id')
->leftjoin('company as cmp','r.sociale_id','=','cmp.id')
->select('ml.*','r.id','r.g_id','r.num','cmp.name')
->where('ml.sent_pst_date','>',$start_date)
->where('ml.sent_pst_date','<',$end_date)
->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I use **whereRaw** (Eloquent) && **Carbon** (dates), for example:

```
$cur_date=Carbon::now();


 $data=DB::table('mailbox_log as ml')
->leftjoin('registration as r','ml.reg_id','=','r.id')
->leftjoin('company as cmp','r.sociale_id','=','cmp.id')
->select('ml.*','r.id','r.g_id','r.num','cmp.name')
->whereRaw("DATEDIFF('" . Carbon::now() . "',created_at)  > 30")
->whereRaw("DATEDIFF('" . Carbon::now() . "',created_at)  < 60")
->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

Please use `->whereRaw()` instead of `->where()`

```
$cur_date=Carbon::now();


 $data=DB::table('mailbox_log as ml')
->leftjoin('registration as r','ml.reg_id','=','r.id')
->leftjoin('company as cmp','r.sociale_id','=','cmp.id')
->select('ml.*','r.id','r.g_id','r.num','cmp.name')
->whereRaw(DB::raw('DATEDIFF(ml.sent_pst_date,$cur_date->format("Y-m-d")','=','30'))
->whereRaw(DB::raw('DATEDIFF(ml.sent_pst_date, "%Y-%m-%d")'),$cur_date->format('Y-m-d'),'<','60')
->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE_FORMAT and CURDATE();

Example:

```
whereRaw('DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d")) > 30 AND 
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d")) < 60 ');
```